# Firefox performance and React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, performance, firefox

I have a strange bug on Mozilla Firefox (latest version).

I have a component that detect the scroll event on its child:

```
const onScroll = useCallback((event: any) => {
    const scrollLeft = event.target.scrollLeft;
    setHorizontalScroll(scrollLeft);
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
    // detect horizontal scroll need to align the headers to body table
    const elementToScroll = getElement();
    if (elementToScroll) {
        elementToScroll.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll, false)
    }
    return () => {
        if (elementToScroll) {
            elementToScroll.removeEventListener('scroll', onScroll, false)
        }
    }
}, [onScroll]);
```

Well, this works fine. I assign as inline style the horizontalScroll in this way

```
<MyElement style{{transform: 'translateX(' + (-horizontalScroll) + 'px)'}}/>
```

The problem is that when scrolling in horizontally, there is a delay between scrolling and translateX, but the strangest thing is if I open the developer tool, everything works fine, because the browser seems to be slower.
I'm going crazy to resolve this issue!

P.s. On Chrome and Safari all works fine.

Thanks. Many thanks if someone can help me :)

Comment: sounds like the smooth scrolling option isn't so smooth. FF might be debouncing the inline style's application. Is translate really the right tool here? You might try side-stepping the inline style application using a CSS var instead. you can still update the var inline, but put the translate rule in a sheet with the value effectively set by your var.

Comment: @dandavis how can I put a variable from js to scss file?
Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: [MDN Using CSS custom properties (variables)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties)

Comment: they work like an attrib does in `content:attr(title);`